# PyQt5: Loading menu from design file

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer

I'm trying to load design file of a main program window. How can I access to menu bar, menus (and submenus) and set up actions?

```
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, design_file='Lab1_Main.ui'):
        super().__init__()
        uic.loadUi(design_file, self)
```

Menu is already implemented to design file

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Any object created in designer is accessible from its [objectName property](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#objectName-prop) when the ui is set up with `uic` methods (or `setupUi` for pyuic generated files).

In your case, the first menu is accessible from `self.ToolsMenu`, its first action is `self.ChangePassword`, etc.

Consider that you can also access the menu bar from the [`menuBar()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#menuBar) function (which returns the current menu bar if it exists, otherwise creates a new one), and you can cycle through its contents using `actions()` as much as any QWidget:

```
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, design_file='Lab1_Main.ui'):
        super().__init__()
        uic.loadUi(design_file, self)
        self.printActions(self.menuBar())

    def printActions(self, obj, indent=0):
        for action in obj.actions():
            if action.isSeparator() and not action.text():
                print('\t' * indent + '[separator]')
            else:
                print('\t' * indent + action.text())
                if action.menu():
                    self.printActions(action.menu(), indent + 1)
```

<sub>A suggestion: avoid using capitalized names for objects; it's common practice (not only for Python) to use capitalized names only for classes and constants, as that practice improves readability since it's much more easy to tell apart classes/constants from functions/variables.</sub>

Comment: The image made me confused since I thought that the .ui had the QMenuBar as toplevel and the OP wanted to place that QMenuBar in the QMainWindow

Comment: @eyllanesc I had a similar thought at the beginning too, but then I realized that (as far as I know of) Designer doesn't allow to create QMenuBar as "new forms", and if you look closely at the image, there's something above the menubar that is clearly not the object inspector's header (also, considering the question, it was unlikely that the OP would have created a QMenuBar form and also renamed it just like Designer does with QMainWindows).

Comment: That they are not in the default elements does not imply that the toplevel of the .ui cannot be modified to use the QMenuBar, so in my test I did it and I thought that the OP had done it too. On the other hand I am very bad to see the details of the images ;-)

Comment: @eyllanesc that's interesting: after modifying the ui, is Designer still capable of loading it correctly as a QMenuBar object?

Comment: 1) Although taking a good look at the status Bar contradicts my assumption. 2) Yes, the Qt Designer renderer can do that, for example the following xml should allow the use of QMenuBar: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MenuBar</class>
 <widget class="QMenuBar" name="MenuBar">
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>`

Comment: @eyllanesc 1) yep, there's that too, I didn't consider it neither :-) 2) I can hardly think about a scenario that would make that *really* useful, but you never know ;-) - maybe some really extensive dynamic QMainWindow creation? In any case, good to know that, thanks!